# Convert Python XML request into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Convert XML request into data frame. Tried using following code but didn't work.

````
data=requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml')
XML_DF = data.content
print('>> XML_DF:', len(XML_DF))
root = ET.XML(XML_DF)
XML_List = []
for child in root[1]:
    XML_Dict = {}
    XML_Dict['CATALOG'] = child.attrib['CATALOG']
    for subchild in child:
        if ''.join(subchild.attrib.values()) == 'CD':
            XML_Dict['Dataset_Name_EN'] = subchild.text
        elif ''.join(subchild.attrib.values()) == 'ARTIST':
            XML_Dict['Dataset_Name_FR'] = subchild.text

    XML_List.append(XML_Dict)
XML_DF = pd.DataFrame(XML_List)```
````

Comment: And what have you tried? Please remember this is not a coding service website. Try to share your code and what have you tried. You can further improve your questions with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What exactly is your "particular scenario"? What output do you get and what output do you want?

Comment: I want to get data from this link "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml" and put into to database as table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write a function which will convert XML to Data frame.For example

````
def SOQL(SOQL):
    qryResult=sf.query_all(SOQL)
    print('Record count{0}'.format(qryResult['totalSize']))
    isDone = qryResult['done']
    if isDone == True:
        df=pd.DataFrame(qryResult['records'])
        df=df.drop('attributes',axis=1)
        return df; ```
````

Comment: Thanks for comment, I changed the wording.